# заменить тире на слеш и точку

Tags: html, wordpress

Добавила запись на сайте, url выглядит так https://vijivuvsegda.ru/kak-orientirovatsya-super-text-html ‎
надо что бы выглядел так  https://vijivuvsegda.ru/kak-orientirovatsya/super-text.html ‎
При создании записи, url меняю и сохраняю, но он возвращается в первоначальный вид. т.е. некорректный. Где и как поправить код?

Comment: Покажиье код, с которым у вас возникли сложности

Answer (score 1):

> Где и как поправить код?

Нигде никакой код править не нужно. Нужно создать нужную иерархию страниц и настроить пермалинки (постоянные ссылки).

Вот только вообще не нужно никаких `.html` в адресах. Как, собственно, и вложенных страниц без необходимости (ради урлов).